# How to determine if character string contains non-Roman characters in R

Tags: regex, r, string

What is the preferred way of determining if a string contains non-Roman/non-English (e.g., **ないでさ**) characters?

Comment: Your question doesn't fit well to the site guidelines. Rephrase it so that you ask how to do something, and more importantly, show what you've tried so far. As it stands, the question is quite broad and "looking for a tool".

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Seems like a perfectly reasonable question and one that is not immediately found on searching. I always have difficulty locating the char-to-integer function. I can never remember if it's char2Int, charToInt, chr2Int, or whatever ... since it's none or those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could determine if string contains non-Latin/non-ASCII characters with `iconv` and `grep`

```
# My example, because you didn't add your data
characters <- c("ないでさ,  satisfação, катынь, Work, Awareness, Potential, für")
# First you convert string to vector of words
characters.unlist <- unlist(strsplit(characters, split=", "))
# Then find indices of words with non-ASCII characters using ICONV
characters.non.ASCII <- grep("characters.unlist", iconv(characters.unlist, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="characters.unlist"))
# subset original vector of words to exclude words with non-ASCII characters
data <- characters.unlist[-characters.non.ASCII]
# convert vector back to a string
dat.1 <- paste(data, collapse = ", ")

# Now if you run 
characters.non.ASCII
[1] 1 2 3 7
```

That means that the first, second, third and seventh indices are non-ASCII characters, in my case 1, 2, 3 and 7 correspond to: **"ないでさ,  satisfação, катынь and  für.**

You could also run

```
dat.1 #and the output will be all ASCII charaters
[1] "Work, Awareness, Potential"
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use regex/grep to check for hex values of characters outside the range of printable ASCII characters:

```
x <- 'ないでさ'
grep( "[^\x20-\x7F]",x )
#[1] 1
grep( "[^\x20-\x7F]","Normal text" )
#integer(0)
```

If you wanted to allow the non-printing ("control") character to be considered "English", you could extend the range of the character class in hte first argument to `grep` to start with "\x01". See `?regex` for more information on using character class argumets. See `?Quotes` for more information about how to specify characters as Unicode, hexadecimal, or octal values.

The R.oo package has conversion functions that may be useful:

```
library(R.oo)
?intToChar
?charToInt
```

The fact that Henrik Bengtsson saw fit to include these in his package says to me that there is no a handy method to do this in base/default R. He's a long-time useR/guRu.

Seeing the other answer prompted this effort which seems straight-forward:

```
> is.na( iconv( c(x, "OrdinaryASCII") , "", "ASCII") )
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: 0x7F is probably not printable.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what output device we are talking about? A TTY might backspace. The R console returns "\177" (octal) from `iconv("\x7f", "", "ASCII")` which is the same as comes back from `R.oo:: intToChar(0x7f)`.

Comment: I think it's the DEL control code, but sure any control code would have an affect on an output device. 7-bit ASCII being 0x00-0x7F